Internal Server Error upon using .htaccess [solved]
I am using ubuntu 24.04 and apache2 webserver.
<VirtualHost *:80>
       <Directory /var/www/testing/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
       </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

This my .htaccess file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC, L]

This the error I am getting

Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error
log.

solved it by using this.
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]


HI Oli, please post your solution as an answer.  And after a day, you are allowed to tick it as the correct answer.  This is a question and answers site!!  Then I can +1 it

i understand that, i instant put solved bcoz i already figured out the issue so other will not waste their time.
